# Credit card company questions

Tags: credit-card

1. What credit card or debit card companies allow for you to set a maximum swipe charge? So that when the limit is above, it either denies it, or texts you for approval. I am not looking for advice on phishing/skimming avoidance.
2. When credit card companies are part of a bank, can they see how much is in your accounts? I'm with 3 banks. Obviously when you're on the phone about your debit card, and want to talk about your credit card, they switch to different phone numbers, making me think the credit card companies are essentially function like completely different companies. But when you 1st open the cc, are they not given how much are in your savings/checkings? Thanks.

Comment: No, I'm aware of work-arounds. Either way, the criminals get the win.

Comment: This reads more like a rant than a question... What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic. In any case, this looks a lot like a hypothetical or XY problem. Millions of people use credit cards on a daily basis, without (major) issues...

Answer (score 4):

Credit cards are generally run by separate companies even when marketed/branded by a bank. If you look carefully, you will usually find that "The Foobash Card", rather than actually being owned by Foobash Savings And Trust is a co-marketing arrangement with someone who specializes in credit card processing (another bank or service). My credit union Visa card, for example, had the credit union's name on it but was one of many operated by a company called (I kid you not) something like Card Handling Services.

Many credit cards will let you request alerts in charges over a certain size, or when a charge puts you close to your limit. If are concerned about skimming, this gives you a better chance to catch large charges immediately. You can report the fraud and have those charges cancelled, of course, but you will probably want to have a new card issued so that account is going to be unavailable to you for a little while..  which is one reason for carrying a second credit card even if you rarely use it.

Comment: I don't like having to cancel charges because it makes you look bad, as well if the credit card company refunds you. Or does the FDIC refund you?

Comment: As far as credit card companies being a separate company, are they under the same CEO, or board of trustees? When it has the same name as a bank?

Comment: @NealConroy - How does flagging a charge as fraudulent "make you look bad"?  To whom do you think it makes you look bad?

Comment: @NealConroy I've had to have transactions marked as fraudulent and cards replaced before, and that's never impacted me negatively. I still have cards with the same bank(s) - they didn't kick me off or lower my limit or anything like that. Re: refunds, the CC company would be the one refunding your account (review your CC terms of service for info regarding your and your CC company's responsibilities when fraudulent transactions occur).

Comment: @NealConroy the FDIC insures deposits (up to 250k/depositor, per bank, per ownership category), as the name implies. It has nothing to do with credit cards.

Comment: @JustinCave 1 of my ccs has a credit line of $7000/month. Don't you think cc companies would be pissed if they kept having to refund me $7000/month? Which is why I would prefer if they allow users to set a maximum swipe charge...

Comment: @NealConroy - If you managed to have a fraudulent charge on your card every month, even if it was $1, the credit card company would certainly have reason to believe that you weren't being appropriately security conscious and might decide to close your account.  If you're being reasonably cautious and still getting fraudulent transactions every couple years, which is reasonably normal, they're not going to care about the amount of the fraudulent transaction (or, more accurately, they rely on their anti-fraud systems to detect fraud and apply different rules depending on the potential loss).

Comment: @JustinCave the issue is, is once the charge happens. Detecting it any time after, is meaningless. Would prefer if it can decline a charge, and text you for your approval.

Comment: @NealConroy several companies let you set transaction limits above which approval is needed (usually in the form of a text/email). But in any event, if your company doesn't, as long as you're getting made whole and you aren't consistently getting defrauded like Justin mentioned, who cares? Your CC company clearly doesn't care enough to implement those kinds of protections for itself, so why should you?

Comment: @NealConroy - I guess we have different definitions of "meaningless".  "I get my money back and have no negative consequences" seems pretty meaningful to me.

Comment: @JustinCave but criminals never get arrested for it. They never refund. CCs refund, but the criminals get the money.

Comment: @StanH cool, none of the 3 cc companies I'm with, allow for it. You're the 1st to mention this. And the 3 ccs I'm with are Chase, Capital 1, and Fidelity.

Comment: @NealConroy - Of course criminals get arrested for it all the time.  Every criminal that defrauds a credit card company doesn't get arrested every time.  But there are plenty of folks in prison for it.

Comment: @JustinCave 1 time a grocery store skimmed my CC card, I reported it to the state's attorney general office, they did nothing to punish them. Another attempted to swipe $550 after I deactivated my card, but because no money was swiped, nobody cared to view the surveillance cameras to catch the culprit, as the intent is there. And so and so forth.

Comment: @NealConroy these are your local politicians, people *you* elect to office - talk to them about law enforcement. But know that it's not at all easy to prove guilt or intent in a criminal case, starting with actually finding the responsible culprit. The CC, after refunding you, recoups its losses from the merchant. So that grocery store is the one left on the hook for the money, and it's in their best interest to not let employees use their store for fraud.

Comment: Punishment for evildoers is _not_ a personal finance issue. For our purposes, you are protected and/or made whole; chasing the perps is not your responsibility nor something you have any control over. The crime was against the CC company, not you, though it was an inconvenience to you. You have no direct evidence of who the perpetrator was and nothing to contribute to the resolution of the matter. Let it go.

Comment: @keshlam, with all due respect, StanH is the only person on track here, he made the "I know of a cc company that does that" and I kindly replied "none of my 3 cc companies allows that feature" aka kindly asking him what those cc companies are. In any event, it didn't happen to my cc, it happened to my state of Illinois welfare card, skimmed $1000, and they only refunded me $562. So, I'm worried, what if it happened to my cc, where 1 has a max limit of $7000. So only StanH replied that there are cc companies that allow to set transaction limits, and I'm asking him to "name drop" them, that's

Comment: @StanH so what cc companies are those?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, it might be company-specific or a feature on certain cards only. I thought CapitalOne had that option because I've definitely had to approve large transactions from my phone, but maybe it's not a user-controlled trigger.

Comment: Welfare cards are debit cards, not credit cards, if I understand correctly. I know Chase lets me set transaction alarms on my card with them; I believe both my credit unions do too. If that's a feature you want, shop for it.

Comment: @keshlam yea, alarm system only notifies you when a big transaction happens, but it doesn't let you approve of it. Looks like nobody in America offers this feature, hmm.

Comment: Nobody has surveyed every bank in America, so someone may offer it... but it seems the small group that answers questions here doesn't have one to offer you. And realtime alarm is actually pretty close; it does let you call the credit card company and immediately challenge that transaction, even if you probably can't block it before the thief gets out of the store.

Answer (score 0):

Individual transaction limits is probably not something they've implemented because it's not something that has a lot of demand from customers.  And it would create ongoing headaches in the support department.

Customers aren't responsible for fraudulent charges as long as they notify the credit card company within a couple months.  If you're the victim of skimming, you have to go through the annoyance of getting a new card and updating payment information for anyone you have autobill the card.  But you're not out any money if the skimmers manage to charge thousands of dollars in electronics, the credit card company is.  That tends to mean that there isn't a huge demand for things like transaction limits from customers.

If a company implemented transaction limits, that would also create a support headache for them.  Whatever limit people chose, they'd periodically want to exceed that limit.  Usually for something really important to them.  They'd get very frustrated when the card company denied their attempt to book a last minute flight for a family funeral or their attempt to buy tickets to that concert/ sporting event for their anniversary.  If they remembered that they had set a transaction limit years ago, sure, they might just go up their limit.  But a lot of them won't remember, will call in to customer service unhappy, and will erode their loyalty.

Comment: US credit cards are meant to be as frictionless as possible, to maximize the number of transactions/fees, which is one of the reasons chip and pin hasn't gotten traction, whereas it's the standard in Europe.

Comment: Um no, if I set a limit for $500, I'm not gonna cry if my airline fee is $550 and cry to the cc company. I can call them to try to make an exception...

Comment: @NealConroy - Perhaps you would be the exceptional customer that set a limit, remembered the limit you set, realized the problem immediately, and calmly called the company to request a change.  That doesn't change the fact that plenty of other customers would behave differently.

Comment: @JustinCave request a change? You mean request an exception, or temporarily request a change?